# How to consume/ receive rabbitmq queue message in Vue js appliaction?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rabbitmq, receiver, real-time-data

I have an application written in spring boot which publishes the message for rabbitmq. and pushed to queue there. I have a front end application written in vue needs to consume the message from rabbitmq. I did a bit google around for related scenarios but can't find much help for it. Is it possible to consume rabbitmq queue message in my vuejs application? if yes how? Thanks for help in advance!!

Comment: [Web-Stomp](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/14/introducing-rabbitmq-web-stomp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Websockets + STOMP (as Randy Casburn commented).

This package can be installed with npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/webstomp-client and used as a service.

Good example can be found here https://github.com/JSteunou/webstomp-client/tree/master/example